# Can we generate random unique alphabets for a textfield in katalon studio?

Tags: katalon-studio

Does anybody know how to generate unique alphabets for text fields in Katalon studio in each new run? Is this done using custom keywords or the codes are written under the Script section?
I tried to create a custom keyword and kept the following code in the keyword but have no idea how to call the function in my test case. Please help

**Code under my custom keyword:**

```
public class testkeyword {

    @Keyword

    def testkeyword() {
        String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        println randomString(chars, 10)
    }

    public static String randomString(String chars, int length) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            sb.append(chars.charAt(rand.nextInt(chars.length())));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'testkeyword' class is probably inside of a package (I will call it 'testpackage') you can see in the test explorer on the left-hand side:

```
Keywords
  + 'testpackage'
      +'testkeyword.groovy'
```

In order to use it in another test case, you will need to import the said package. Add the following import statement at the top of the test case file:

```
import testpackage.testkeyword
```

And then call the function with

```
testkeyword.testkeyword()
```

inside of the test case.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I followed your suggestion and did accordingly but now I am getting the following error :                                                                        groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static package1.customfunctions.testkeyword() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: testkeyword()

Comment: Have you changed the class name? Because in the original post the class is called "testkeyword" and in that message the class is "customfunctions"...

Comment: Yes I changed the class name to customfunctions and renamed it wherever needed. But no any other changes have been made other than that. Can you please suggest why am I getting this error:                                                           groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static package1.customfunctions.testkeyword() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: testkeyword()

Comment: Can you please share the part of the code where you are invoking the method?

Comment: Yes, sure!           WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/group create/Page_FoneCreditAdmin/input_Name_form-control ng-untouched ng-pri_24ff78'), 
CustomKeywords.'package1.customfunctions.testkeyword'())

Comment: Try `WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/group create/Page_FoneCreditAdmin/input_Name_form-control ng-untouched ng-pri_24ff78'), customfunctions.testkeyword())`, without the CustomKeywords. Also add `import static package1.customfunctions` to the top of the script.